# SELECT in WHERE IN subquery

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT u.*, m.first_name, m.last_name
FROM unit u
INNER JOIN member m
ON m.id = u.member_id
WHERE u.id in (SELECT p.id FROM property p
               WHERE p.member_id = 1 and p.is_deleted = 0) AND
      u.is_deleted = 0
```

This does not generate what I want. The sub-query in the WHERE IN part (select p.id from property p where p.member_id = 1 and p.is_deleted = 0) returns 1,2,3,6 if I run it separately, but the full query seems like it is only getting 1 as a result from the sub-query?

Anyone?

EDIT: Have attached screens of the results below:

1) Full query results:

[image]

2) Sub-query results

[image]

3) Unit table

[image]

4) Property table

[image]

Comment: how are we supposed to fix your query without some sample data and the expected results?

Comment: @LelioFaieta We can't (I think).

Comment: Your subquery is good, the problem is probably in the second condition  `u.is_deleted = 0`

Comment: are the others not returned because  `u.is_deleted = 1`

Comment: Have you tried it ?
select GROUP_CONCAT(p.id) as pids  from property p
               where p.member_id = 1 and p.is_deleted = 0 GROUP BY p.id

Comment: try this in your sub query

Comment: @AbdulrehmanSheikh didn't work :(

Comment: Have added images, my bad.

Comment: Your sub query result is not good

Comment: it should be comma separated ids

Comment: For your help I have to build the same columns and test on my localhost ... let me do it

Comment: @AbdulrehmanSheikh thanks, ill gladly wait :)

Comment: In your Unit table, there are only 4 ids. (1,2,3,4). 4 is irrelevant since it's member_id is 2. In your Property table, there are 6 ids. (1-6). 5 is irrelevant (is_deleted = 1). 6 is not in the Unit table. So, your query match only 1,2 and 3 as expected.

Comment: @DxTx the unit with ID 4 should be listed as well.

Comment: @DxTx ah you are right... I missed that property with id 4 had member_id 2.... I set it to 1 and it returns fine. Sorry everyone!

Comment: It cannot be listed because of your sub query. Give me all the rows (`1,2,3,4`) if they are in (`1,2,3,6`)
Result: `1,2,3`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your correct query. Your mistake was with IN() clause. Check below if its correct.

```
select u.*, m.first_name, m.last_name 
from unit u 
inner join member m on m.id = u.member_id 
where u.is_deleted = 0 
AND u.property_id IN 
(select pr.id as pids from property pr where pr.member_id = 1 and pr.is_deleted = 0)
```

Check screenshot for results.
[image]